# Good Bootstrap form validator

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, bootstrap

I'm looking for a good Bootstrap Form Validator library which is free for commercial purposes. Something like the below reference image http://formvalidation.io.

After a long time of Google searching I didn't find a form validator similar to below image:

> [image: BootStrap Validator]

Right now I'm using jQuery ValidationEngine but I don't like the UI when I have many fields:

> [image: Validation Engine]

Answer (score 1):

[Formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io/) is quite good. And if the project gets commercial it won't be too expensive to use it. But anyway, I would like to provide you an good openSource alternative.

You can try to use [jqBootstrapValidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) too. It's free of charge and can be downloaded on [GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveRaven/jqBootstrapValidation). It's published under MIT, you need to be sure that this license matches your development.